# HTTP Status 500 - Servlet execution threw an exception Please

Tags: java

[image]

I have done everything and it's not working.

Comment: Please share your servlet code and full stack trace.

Comment: Please you didn't setup the image link well.

Comment: @Pcechz did my answer help you? If yes, could you please accept it and if not, could you explain how we could help you solving your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your question is very minimalistic. You should give at least a little insight to your code.

Orcale documentation says: [`AbstractMethodError` is] Thrown when an application tries to call an abstract method. Normally, this error is caught by the compiler; this error can only occur at run time if the definition of some class has incompatibly changed since the currently executing method was last compiled.

As I recall it is a compatibility error: it's about the version number in web.xml. At least this is my suspicion. [Check this thread here](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/54950-java-lang-abstractmethoderror) for further information, it solved my problem earlier.

Comment: Please quote the relevant part of the thread you link to in your answer and provide the link for additional reference only.  Links may not last forever, so this answer may become useless.

Comment: @daiscog it's about the version number in web.xml. At least this is my suspicion

Comment: It could well be.  But without explicitly stating that above, this answer is incomplete.

Comment: @daiscog I appended it in my answer.